# pip install psycopg2==2.7.3 fails with exit status 1120

Tags: python, cmd, psycopg2

When I run the 'pip install psycopg2==2.7.3' it basically explodes with an error code 1 and exit status 1120. I am on Windows 10 and am at a loss because I can barely even being to parse this error message. Any help would be appreciated.

The PATH is set correctly I believe, I tried to get mod_wsgi since some had said it helped with an exit code 1120, but I actually get the same error when trying to install that.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27702\bin\Hostx86\x86>pip install psycopg2==2.7.3
Collecting psycopg2==2.7.3
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/98/99/33ca02c4bc3ed1bd9ceab5614bda2e6d1d31e61ec58345b9feece238c38a/psycopg2-2.7.3.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: psycopg2
  Found existing installation: psycopg2 2.8.2
    Uninstalling psycopg2-2.8.2:
      Successfully uninstalled psycopg2-2.8.2
  Running setup.py install for psycopg2 ... error
    ERROR: Complete output from command 'c:\users\gehri\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\gehri\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-2kq90f3y\\psycopg2\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\gehri\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-giee18ni\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    ERROR: running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7
[...................................]
    lobject_int.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lo_close
    adapter_binary.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _PQescapeByteaConn
    adapter_binary.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _PQescapeBytea
    build\lib.win32-3.7\psycopg2\_psycopg.cp37-win32.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 68 unresolved externals
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.21.27702\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120
    ----------------------------------------
  Rolling back uninstall of psycopg2
  Moving to c:\users\gehri\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\psycopg2-2.8.2.dist-info\
   from c:\users\gehri\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\~sycopg2-2.8.2.dist-info
  Moving to c:\users\gehri\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\
   from c:\users\gehri\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\~sycopg2
ERROR: Command "'c:\users\gehri\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\gehri\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-2kq90f3y\\psycopg2\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\gehri\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-giee18ni\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\gehri\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2kq90f3y\psycopg2\
```

For a bit more reference I am running in Windows 10 with a command prompt run as administrator.

Comment: Are you running in an elevated shell?

Comment: administrator command prompt at the moment.

Comment: You should be able to get around the problem by `pip install psycopg2-binary==2.7.3.2`. What's your *PostgreSQL* version? Also, for more output try: `pip install psycopg2==2.7.3 -v`. Also what does `pg_config --version` output (in *cmd*)?

Comment: Postgre is 11.3.

Comment: as for the -v.. yes I did get more information.. pages and pages of it which I can't even imagine what to do with.

Comment: You should search for *link* in that verbose output, and paste that info in the question :)

Comment: make sure your pip is up to date via `pip install -U pip` before `pip install psycopg2-binary`, I've just been through 3 hours of inscrutable error messages :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it just by installing a proper version of python (64-bit instead of 32-bit).

Just be attentive and download WindowX86-64 version in case your PC is 64-bit. Also, you have to install postgreSQL and set in your PATH variables; e.g. `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin` is the path I see on my PC.